# Map is flipped and turned when reading GML data with r

Tags: r, gis

I have downloaded a [GML-File](https://inspire.lfrz.gv.at/000606/ds/WLV_GZP.zip) from [this Website](https://geometadatensuche.inspire.gv.at/metadatensuche/srv/api/records/298a3eb3-0190-4ae3-b1ab-21b34a83d2b0).

Then I use the following code to process this file in `R`:

```
library(rgdal)
test <- readOGR(dsn='WLV_GZP.gml')
```

I am printing the map like this:

```
test3 <- subset(test, qualitativeValue=='Rote Zone Lawine') #For speeding up the Test-print
plot(test3)
```

The result is turned 90 degrees to the right and flipped (East-West). How can I get this map to work? Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit: The result is the same when using the `sf` library:

```
 test4 <- sf::st_read('WLV_GZP.gml') 
 test4 <- subset(test4, qualitativeValue=='Rote Zone Lawine') 
 plot(test4)
```

In order to inspect the bbox I transform the map:

```
roads <- st_transform(test4, crs = 4326)
```

This yields a bbox:

```
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -23.4819 ymin: 58.59924 xmax: -18.90591 ymax: 62.56157
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
```

Since the map displays Austria this is of course way off...

PS: I would like to post a PNG-File but I received an error when uploading the file.

Comment: You or your program are missunderstanding GML/WFS axis ordering - see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/296518/79 for more details

Comment: (Note: zip file is a 158Mb download, unzips to 700Mb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the GDAL SWAP_COORDINATES option. It can take one of three values:

```
> d_NO = st_read("./WLV_GZP.gml", options=list("SWAP_COORDINATES=NO"))
> d_YES = st_read("./WLV_GZP.gml", options=list("SWAP_COORDINATES=YES"))
> d_AUTO = st_read("./WLV_GZP.gml", options=list("SWAP_COORDINATES=AUTO"))
```

resulting in, for your data:

```
> st_bbox(d_NO)
   xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax 
4285465 2599037 4824292 2888410 
> st_bbox(d_YES)
   xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax 
2599037 4285465 2888410 4824292 
> st_bbox(d_AUTO)
   xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax 
2599037 4285465 2888410 4824292
```

The `d_NO` data are in Austria.

I don't know if there's a definitive way of deciding for a given dataset whether to swap or not, the AUTO default should, I imagine, work for a correctly specified data set but if something is out of spec then who knows...